# Conflicts between Circuitikz and Babel

Tags: errors, babel, circuitikz, spanish

I'm work on a project in which i include `circuitkz` and `biblatex` for bibliography.

When i try to use `american voltage` option from `circuitkz` package a biber error appear without reason.

### EDIT:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}    
\setlength{\columnsep}{20.0pt}
\usepackage[style=ieee,texencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\let\cite\parencite
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{v/.append style={/tikz/american voltages}}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
      \draw
      (0,0) to[sV]
      (0,2) to[R, v^>=$v_1$]  %%This is the problem. 
      (3,2) to[C]
      (3,0) -- (0,0)
      ;
    \end{circuitikz}


\nocite{vibrations_waves}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

When i use just `(0,2) to[R]` instead the line above, every thing render correctly.

```
%%%%%%%    ref.bib   %%%%%%%%%
@Book{vibrations_waves,
author = {George C. King},
title = {Vibrations and Waves},
publisher = {Wiley},
year = {2009},
}
```

### Afeter editing, i notice that the really problem is `babel` package. When i comment the line `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` every thing works.

Comment: Please don't post links to your whole document. Create a minimal working document that shows the problem and edit your question to include that document. It should only load the packages that cause the problem to show up and only enough code to demonstrate it.

Comment: ok, i ll change it in a second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual problem with `babel` shorthands. You cure it with `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\ctikzset{v/.append style={/tikz/american voltages}}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
  \draw (0,0) to [sV]
        (0,2) to [R, v^>=$v_1$]  %%This is the problem.
        (3,2) to [C]
        (3,0) -- (0,0)
  ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had no idea this TikZ library existed. I think this is a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

As you note in the question, the problem has nothing to do with `biblatex` but with the `spanish` option of `babel`.  This is due to the `>` shorthand defined in the Spanish `babel`.  If you don't need or use the shorthands at all then you can turn them off globally with the package option `es-noshorthands`.

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
```

Alternatively if you need the shorthands, you can disable the offending one (`>`) within the `circuitikz` environment:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{circuitikz}{\spanishdeactivate{>}}
```

Here's a complete document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}    

\setlength{\columnsep}{20.0pt}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
% or if you don't need shorthands at all:
%\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{v/.append style={/tikz/american voltages}}   
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{circuitikz}{\spanishdeactivate{>}}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
      \draw
      (0,0) to[sV]
      (0,2) to[R, v^>=$v_1$]  %%This is the problem. 
      (3,2) to[C]
      (3,0) -- (0,0)
      ;
    \end{circuitikz}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly `es-noquoting` is sufficient.